# express server not working in electron app

Tags: reactjs, express, electron, electron-builder

i have created a `electron app`  it has `react js and express.js` with `electron .` command the app is working fine the electron app starts the react and express js

the issue is when i tyed to make a exe file out of it  i used  `electron-builder` package to build the exe app  the app is build sccessfully and the app starts when i open the `myapp.exe` file react loads correctly but express server is not loading i am not sure what i am doing wrong

i have added a command in pakage.js to add the server.js to build folder i am not sure that is the way it has to be done

`"build": "react-scripts build && copyfiles -f server.js build"`
this is my main.js i have added it in the public folder

// main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
let expressServer;

app.on("ready", () => {
  // Spawn the Express server
  expressServer = spawn("node", [
    path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "server.js"),
  ]);

  const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
        enableRemoteModule: true,
      },
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html`);
  };

  createWindow();

  app.on("activate", () => {.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

app.on("before-quit", () => {
  expressServer.kill();
});
```

this is my server.js it is in the root folder

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
  // add a console.log statement here to confirm that the server has started
  console.log("Express server started successfully");
});
```